# non-persisting state between function calls in React.js

Tags: reactjs, ethereum

Generally, I am trying to load some data when component loads (in initialiseSellerData() ) but I only want to do this once, i.e. if page is refreshed it doesn't do it again. Please see attempt below and description of specific problem beneath

```
class Index extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        initialised: false
    };
}

componentDidMount = () => 
{
    this.initialised()
    if(this.state.initialised == false)
    {
        this.initialiseSellerData();
    }   
}


initialiseSellerData = async () => 
{
   // this function makes a call to contract to initialise data
}

initialised = async () => 
{
    const {sellContract } = this.props
    const response = await sellContract.methods.initialised().call()
    if(response == true)
    {
        this.setState({initialised: true})
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that in componentDidMount, initialised() function is called correctly and initialises state gets set to true however then when do I the check for initialised it returns false (should return true). Why isn't my state persisting / being passed between function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to use `await`.  `initialised` is an async function. so the calling function should use `await` or `then` to handle the promise.

```
componentDidMount = async () => 
{
    await this.initialised()  
}


initialiseSellerData = async () => 
{
   // this function makes a call to contract to initialise data
}

initialised = async () => 
{
    const {sellContract } = this.props
    const response = await sellContract.methods.initialised().call()
    if(response == true)
    {
        await initialiseSellerData();
        this.setState({initialised: true});
    }
}
```

Comment: and even then it may not working since `setState` call inside is not guaranteed to be sync